# Enque Javascript in Footer?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I currently enque jQuery like so - how do I move this to the footer instead?

```
// Enque: jQuery
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to move it to the footer?  What are you trying to that requires you to deregister core's jquery?

Comment: Why even replace the internal library? (with an older version mind you) Is there some special functionality that version provides that you need? Additionally you don't need that `is_admin()` check, that action doesn't run in the admin.

Comment: Also, the last param of both [`wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) defines whether to load the script in the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fifth parameter is `$in_footer`. You have left that out. Add that parameter, set it to `true`.

```
wp_register_script(
  'jquery',
  "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js",
  false,
  null,
  true
);
```

But I echo the concern expressed by @Andrew in a comment. You can cause yourself trouble by deregistering/replacing the core libraries.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Answer (score 3):

[`wp_register_script()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_register_script/) takes boolean for last argument `$in_footer` (default `false`) to achieve this.

Note that it is strongly considered best practice to use same version WP core uses (determined by code) rather than hardcode arbitrary one.